# alternative way to load fast with more than 2000+ records database

Tags: .net, database, vb.net

Are there any recommendations/suggestions on how to load faster with records having 2000+?

When loading data, systems seems to freeze for a sec while loading more data. Basically what I want is that maybe wait for progressbar to finish load all data records or something

```
    Sub loadcheck()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from tblstore ORDER by storecode, check_date, ID ASC", conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr.Item("ID"), dr.Item("storecode"), dr.Item("check_date"), dr.Item("check_num"), dr.Item("check_name"), dr.Item("check_memo"), dr.Item("check_amount"), dr.Item("date_release"), dr.Item("date_deposit"), dr.Item("status"))
        End While
        dr.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    conn.Close()
End Sub

 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
     loadcheck()

 End Sub

 Private Sub manageCheck_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     managesupplier.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
     Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
 End Sub
```

Comment: Fill a `DataTable` then set `DataGridView.DataSource` to the DataTable. I suspect your current code redraws the grid after each row

Comment: If you ever feel that you need to set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `False` then you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you should be using data binding. ALWAYS bind data unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise. If you don't know whether you have a specific reason, you don't.

In this case, you can still retrieve the data using a `BackgroundWorker` if you want, although you probably don't even need to. You absolutely MUST populate the grid on the UI thread though.

```vb
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"),
          command As New OleDbCommand("SQL query here", connection)
        connection.Open()

        Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            Dim table As New DataTable

            table.Load(reader)
            e.Result = table
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Dim table = DirectCast(e.Result, DataTable)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
End Sub
```

Note the use of `Using` blocks to properly dispose all disposable objects. If you're not modifying and saving the data then using a data reader is fine. If you want to make changes, use a data adapter instead, which can move data both ways.

Actually, it occurs to me that the `DataSource` property is type `Object` anyway, so there's no need to cast `e.Result`:

```vb
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    DataGridView1.DataSource = e.Result
End Sub
```

Comment: with that code, is it possible also to populate the column for the datagridview? Like I wanna customize the header text and only display the column that I want to. I'm more familiary with my current populate loadcheck setup, so any workaround with my current code implementing with backgroundworker.

Comment: @NnekLecxe, if you only want certain columns then you should specify those columns in your query instead of using 'select *'. You can also create the grid columns in the designer and set their DataPropertyName properties to specify which data source property to bind to.

Comment: You can also programmatically set the column header text in `BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted()` by adding this after setting the `.DataSource`: `DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Foo"`  `DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Bar"`

Comment: I'm currently stuck on setting up my datagridview manually by code.  I have my ready datagridview with designated header (and some hidden headers that i dont need already), but I'm somewhat lost on how will i load my new datatable. It seems to repopulate new ID, etc from database to datagrid. The datagridview with readymade headers are becoming useless. It won't load under my header from datagridiview

Comment: @NnekLecxe, if the columns you have added are not being populated then you must not have done as already instructed. You need to set the `DataPropertyName` of each column to tell them which column/property of the data source to bind to. Only add the columns you need, configure their binding as instructed and then set `AutoGenerateColumns` on the grid to `False` before setting the `DataSource`. The existing grid columns will bind to the data source columns/properties as specified and no additional columns will be generated.